# how to change image size use Wordpress visual composer post grid custom query

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress with visual composer, I write custom query for post grid , but it get the image size with 1024x1024 which is not fit my theme, I want to change the image to medium one, any one can help me? Thanks very much.